# Universe expansion, sub-luminal velocity elements?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, space-expansion

### It's not another question about the mechanism of expansion velocity exceeding c

Much literature is devoted to describing the expansion of the universe measured by Hubble's Law - how the speed of light is exceeded to $\approx3c$ and the theory explaining this as due to the creation of new space homogenously throughout the universe. It is remarkable, of course; but I wanted to ask about other contributing mechanisms. A little trouble finding answers...?

### Sub-luminal Velocity Expansion?

Must surely exist because gravity should simply have a sub-luminal deccelerating effect on expansion of the universe, for example. I suppose this would encompass the effect of dark matter. (Sorry no idea about dark energy's role).

Is that "assumption" consistent with current understanding?

### Assuming Yes, Only Raised More Questions

I imagined that this would create some directional component to the rate of expansion of the universe (as radial and circumfrential components of this part of interstella velocities would be different by around $2\pi$).

I do see some deviations in the last decade in the measurements of $H_0$, ranging 67 to 74.75 (Noting this exceeds published uncertainties, does anyone have a non-sociology theory what's behind that?).

Is the idealised Hubble law (which states the effect is directionally homogenous) just a theorum, or has directional homogenuity been verified to some level of accuracy?

Not sure where this leads. Could it one day give us a direction towards the center of the actual universe (not the observable universe), for example.

Can anyone clarify current understanding?

Answer (score 3):

The measurements of of Hubble's constant (i.e., Hubble parameter now) have varied more than that over the years. See the summary of the data and the reasons going back to 1920. Still, the most interesting graphics and data there are more recent, since 2000. See it at https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~dfabricant/huchra/hubble/

They just use a lot of different ways of determining the number, it shows some of them. The most recent and accepted numbers seem to be towards the lower end, like 67 km/sec/Mpsec. See the numbers from Wikipedia, at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble's_law, mostly 67 to 72.

Yes, there are some around the 70, and some at around 67, and yes the differences are larger than the uncertainties, but those are not 5 sigma numbers. They are 68% numbers typically, that's one sigma. See the numbers from the Planck data release, it shows less variation when averaged with various measurements. See it at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_(spacecraft)#2015_data_release

As for isotropy and homogeneity the measurements are from various wavelengths and effects. Large sky surveys are done both optically and at radio frequencies, and have found largely the homogeneity and isotropy. More stunning is of course the Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB) which shows the very very small inhomogeneities and anisotropies in the CMB temperature, which were all from around 380,000 years after the Big Bang. After that there was structure formation (galaxies and stars), but still the large scale isotropy and homogeneity at scales of a 100 Mpsec and higher. It's not assumed, it is measured. Assumptions in cosmologies didn't go too well for people over history, and even during Einstein the assumption was it was static until they saw the expansion.

Other standard current understanding: there is no center to the universe, the Big Bang happened everywhere at once, and the resulting universe expanded where everything went away from each other. Think of the ink dots drawn on the surface of an inflating balloon, they are spread out from each other.

Subluminal expansion: yes, until you go out to about 13 billion light years away from us the expansion is subluminal. That's a redshift of about 1, and it happened about 8 billion years after the Big Bang, reaching c then, now those galaxies are about 13 billion light years from us, and maximizing at 3c asymptotically now. Since it is accelerating it'll go faster. Google universe history and expansion, you'll see some of the epochs and times, maybe some show speeds also. They are well understood.

What is stil somewhat mysterious is:
-Galaxy formation, and the large voids and over densities we see here and there. Lots of work on it.
-what actually is the dark matter? It is thought it is some very weakly interacting massive particles left over from the early universe. Because it interacts so little it is hard to detect the actual particles. Plenty research and searches on it. 
-dark energy: that is more mysterious, and it is thought to be the energy of vacuum fluctuations. But we don't understand why they are so small, theory predicts larger numbers, and to be what it is it is believed there has to be some symmetries to cancel things out we still don't see. Exploring physics at higher energies may give some answers. 
-so larger space telescopes are getting built, and also the nascent field of gravitational wave observatories can help us by allowing us to 'see' beyond the CMB (i.e., to before the 380,000 years after the Big Bang, and see what gravitational structures we see, possibly some exotic unknown matter.

I hope this gives you an idea of how cosmology and high energy physics are now so related and so dynamic, even though progress is by nature slow because so expensive to build the larger telescopes and larger accelerometers.

Comment: Thanks for the tour - CMD anisotropy is fascinating, although it gives us motion relative to an observable universe.

To spell out the answer to my specific question I think it is that $H_0$ measurements set limits on isotropy predicted in Hubble's law.

Comment: CMD => CMB! oops